# acronyms on Elastic Search request

Tags: json, elasticsearch, post

Please, I have a request on Elastic search and I'm trying to add a list of acronyms (or synonyms) inside the request. But I can't figure out where to place it.
Let's say the synonymes list is {'HR': 'Human Ressources", "AWS": "Amazon Web Service"} 
 
The request is the following:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "observatory": [
                            "rome",
                            "meban",
                            "emass",
                            "cigref",
                            "opiiec",
                            "null"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "referentiel_id": [
                            "null",
                            42,
                            48,
                            52
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "skill": {
                        "query": "*dactif*",
                        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [synonym token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) to handle synonyms in your search query

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "synonym"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "HR, Human Ressources",
              "AWS, Amazon Web Service"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "observatory": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "synonym"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "observatory":"HR"
}
{
    "observatory":"Human Ressources"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "observatory": {
              "query": "HR"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67707925",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.487735,
        "_source": {
          "observatory": "Human Ressources"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67707925",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.487735,
        "_source": {
          "observatory": "HR"
        }
      }
    ]
```